# How to disable Reactive Elasticsearch repository interface scanning

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

How to disable Reactive Elasticsearch repository interface scanning by default

```
2021-02-06 10:55:59.723  INFO 32765 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Reactive Elasticsearch repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-02-06 10:55:59.777  INFO 32765 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 53 ms. Found 0 Reactive Elasticsearch repository interfaces.
```

Comment: this doc help. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/repository/config/EnableReactiveElasticsearchRepositories.html